# Use of the Word "Shoah" Before the Holocaust

Tags: words, holocaust-shoah

Are there any Hebrew texts that employ the word "Shoah" to refer to calamities that befell the Jewish people prior to the 20th century? Or is the use of "Shoah" to refer to the assault against Jews as perpetrated by the Nazis and their collaborators the first instance of its being employed in such a fashion?

I am interested in knowing whether this is but a further instance of the word's being used to refer to a widespread destruction, or if it is something altogether new. And if it *is* something new, was there any opposition to it?

Comment: I am nominating this question to be re-opened. I have read the requirements for questions on this Stack Exchange, and fail to see how this one doesn't qualify. It is a question about language, to be sure, but language *as relates to Judaism*.

Comment: I would be willing to agree if this question is edited to limit it to a significant text, like, say, the passuk where the term comes from. As it stands now, I would have closed it as too broad, actually.